# What is the counterpart of piping a schema into sqlite in Linux to Windows (Flask)

Tags: python, linux, windows, flask, sqlite

I am following the tutorial on the [Flask's website](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/dbinit/#tutorial-dbinit)

To give you some context, I am working in a directory flaskapp that has the flaskr.py file and schema.sql. The virtualenv is activated.

schema.sql is

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
id integer primary key autoincrement,
title text not null,
text text not null
);
```

flaskr.py with unneccesary part trimmed:

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
            db.commit()
```

The concerned part in the tutorial says-

> Flaskr is a database powered application as outlined earlier, and more precisely, an application powered by a relational database system. Such systems need a schema that tells them how to store that information. So before starting the server for the first time it’s important to create that schema.
>
> Such a schema can be created by piping the schema.sql file into the sqlite3 command as follows:

```
sqlite3 /tmp/flaskr.db < schema.sql
```

I am pretty sure that I have located the problem, because on running it, the error is:

```
File "C:\Users\Hp1\Desktop\flaskr\flaskrapp\flaskr.py", line 19,
in connect_db
return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The 'DATABASE' in my flaskr.py file is '/tmp/flaskr.db'. So I made a blank flaskrdb.db file in my working directory and replaced the 'tmp/flaskr.db' in the flaskr.py DATABASE value. But I am unable to use the piping operation, because it is given for Linux. How do I do that in Windows?
I am unable to find sqlite3.exe anywhere on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to use your existing Python installation and do it by hand, just for the purpose of your tutorial.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("flaskr.db") # Replace this with the path to the flaskr.db in your working directory
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("drop table if exists entries;")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002C3BB90>
>>> c.execute("""create table entries (
... id integer primary key autoincrement,
... title text not null,
... text text not null
... );""")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002C3BB90>
>>>
```

If you're going to need to interact with sqlite3 databases more, consider installing and learning the tools from the SQLite website: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html -- You'll want sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3110100.zip.
There is a commandline sqlite application distributed with those tools which will work with the piping example from the tutorial.